# True/false questions on image kernel and basis of vector spaces and subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

1) The set ${t + 1, t2 + 2, t2 + t}$ is a basis of $F_3[t]≤2$.
I put false because if t is 2, then we have ${t + 1, 0 , t2 + t}$ so a non zero coefficient could exist.

2) T : V → V a linear transformation of a vector space V. If  $ker T ∩ Im T = {0}$ then T is injective. Im not sure about this at all.

3) Let $A ∈ M_{p×n}$ and $B ∈ M_{p×1}$. $AX = B$ a system of unknowns $X1, . . . , Xn$. If the rank of matrix A is p, then the system has at least 1 solution.

Comment: For 2 start with a 2d space, if T^2=0 then clearly the image would be a subspace of the kernel. Find a matrix that has a kernel but T^2 is not zero.

Answer (score 2):

**To a)**

It follows from the answer by @MattS that it is false.

**To b)**

Consider $T=0.$ Then, $\mathrm{im}(T)=\{0\},$ from where $\mathrm{ker}(T)\cap\mathrm{im}(T)=\{0\}.$ Now, $ \mathrm{ker}(T)=V.$ Thus, if $V\ne \{0\}$ $T$ is not injective.

**To c)**

It is $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(A|B)=p.$ So using the theorem of Rouche-Capelli we get that there is at least one solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to 1) is false. To prove this, note that
$$t+1-(t^2+t)+(t^2+2)=0$$
assuming $F_3$ is the field with 3 elements.

2) is also false. Consider the map $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ sending $(x,y)\mapsto (x,0)$.

3) is true. We may use Gaussian elimination to prove this.

Comment: Note that $t+1-(t^2+t)+(t^2+2)=3.$

Comment: @mfl note that the field appears to be of characteristic 3, so 3=0.

Comment: I have realized that. Thank you for noticing it.